# implement of DFS algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

i would like to check myself whether following procedures for DFS -Depth First search is correct(  so i would like to check if i understood it correctly)
we have following Graph
[image]

we use stack for DFS, so let start : 
initially vertex A is added to the stack and it is marked as visited(first output is A), next  adjacent element are (B,C,D), first let add B, because  B has no any adjacent element pop B(so we have A B), now next visiting element of A is C, we  push C on stack and C will be also output (A B C),  C has only non visited element K, so add k to the stack and  write on  output (A B C K), K  we has following non visited elements D and and L, push  D(A B C K D), but D has no non visited adjacent vertex , so pop from stack  , and push L, (A B C K D L), now L has only J so push J ( A B C  K D L J) and J has only M so finally we have
A B C K D L J M

am i right?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you said but in case you chose to discover L from node K that is incorrect. You go to node K from node D. 
So basically the DFS graph has the following arcs:(A,B), (A,C), (C,K), (K,D),(D,L), (L,J), (J,M).

Comment: aaaa  one mistake right, from D i can go to  L, right i saw now

Comment: Small mistake. Keep up the good work !!

Comment: what about BFS ?

Comment: Try yourself first and I shall correct you if needed ;)

Comment: My teacher once told me a very good example to remember BFS and DFS.  You go to a party and you bring some friends with you. In DFS you go to the checklist and you enter first and than your friends and then the rest of people in line. In BFS you enter but your friends are told to stay at the back of the queue in case there is any place left for them to enter.

Comment: ok i will post here  as  an answer for BFS

Comment: i think i done it correctly

Comment: Yeah:-) good job!

Comment: thanks  very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

so for breadth first algorithm we use  Queue  -FIFO=first in first out, first will be node  A, new  A  has  three node  which is adjacent  , alphabetically   we push

```
 B 
 C 
 D,
```

now current working node is B, B has no any adjacent node, so deque B ( we have A B as list),in queue we have left

C 
D
so current working node is C   and remove from queue (A B C), now C  has only non visited node  K so  enque in queue , we have

D
K
now currently  working node is D, we has L  as  an visited so enque L and remove D

( A B C D) 
K
L
now  K  has no any  non visited so deque it ( A B C D K), now  we gave L  on top of queue , deque L( A B C D K L) and  L has only J so enqueue J 
(A B C D K L J M) will be answer   i think i am right